# extracting string with Indexof in c#

Tags: c#, indexof

I am trying to extract the number portion in this filename. "Name, lastname_123456_state_city.pdf"

I have got this far..

```
idstring = file.Substring(file.IndexOf("_") + 1, 
    (file.LastIndexOf("_") - file.IndexOf("_") - 1));
```

Comment: Will number always be after the first dash?  You could use Split on _ and grab the first element of the array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of those cases where a regex might be better:

```
_(\d+)_
```

And, here is how you would use it

```
    string input = "Name, lastname_123456_state_city.pdf";
    string regexPattern = @"_(\d+)_";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
    string yourNumber = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var firstUnderscore = file.IndexOf("_");
var nextUnderscore = file.IndexOf("_", firstUnderscore + 1);
var idstring = file.Substring(firstUnderscore + 1, nextUnderscore - firstUnderscore - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could pick two answers!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a regular expression? Testing for `@"_([0-9]*)_"` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^.*_(?<number>\d+)_.*\.pdf");
var idstring=regex.Match(file).Groups["number"].Value;
```